# getwindow() inside a view in service

Tags: android, service

I am trying to develop a lock screen. I am placing a view from my service that acts as a lock screen and display in front of all activities and i'm almost finished with it. But from my service, i am not able to access getwindow() propery to provide the following

```
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it

Just add

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN 
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

and add it to the view

Answer (score 1):

First of all u have to understand use of service. service is non-gui thread which can run in the background. if u want ui start activity from service or send a broadcast to already existing activity.

Comment: i am trying to override the home button. By placing a view in service, it will always remin in the front of off other activities

Comment: Service is not a thread, and the fact that it doesn't have UI doesn't mean is on background. As a matter of fact, android.app.Service runs on the ui thread, and you have to make sure you handle threading correctly